# replace upper case character with dash and lowercase

Tags: bash, docker

Hi I have this bash script with loop through every directories and build it

```
for d in * ; 
  do (cd ./"$d" && docker build -t "$d" .); 
done
```

the problem is docker does not support uppercase for images name, so with the directory named `repairService` I want to rename the images to `service-desk`.

How do I achive that with bash scripting

Also I don't want to build it with docker compose so don't answer it with docker compose

Comment: `if [[ $d = repairService ]]; then d=service-desk; fi`?

Comment: Please edit your question and explain the logic of your renaming scheme. Just in case it consists in removing a leading `repair`, converting to lower case and appending `-desk` you can try: `cd "$d"; d="${d#repair}"; docker build -t "${d,}-desk" .`

Comment: `for d in * ; 
  do (cd ./"$d" && docker build -t $(echo "$d" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]") .); 
done` if you just want to convert everything to local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IF condition is added & then the variable value is reassigned.

```
#!/bin/sh
for d in *; 
do 
    if [ "$d" = "repairService" ]; 
    then d="service-desk"; 
    fi; 
echo "$d"; # Your docker operation here
done
```